# Facebook xd_arbiter.php JSON.parse

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've put together a test site to try and get facebook login working with the following code, but I get two errors showing up in FireBug which doesn't seem to effect the functionality of the web page when I just ignore them and carry on.

HTML:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" show-faces="true" autologoutlink="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></div>
<div id="FBLogin"><a id="FBLoginLnk" href="#" title="Login with Facebook"><img src="./login-button.png" /></a></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
      $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
      FB.init({
          appId: "012345678901234",
          status: true, // check login status
          channelUrl : '//website.co.uk/bla/channel.php', // Channel File
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
          oauth: true
      });    

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function() {
            console.timeStamp("Login even")

            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    console.log("Connected Event");
                    // Good to go       
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    console.log("Not Authorized Event");
                    NotLoggedIn();  
                }else{
                    console.log("Not Logged In Event");
                    NotLoggedIn();              
                }
            });

        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                console.timeStamp("getLoginStatus")
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    console.log("Connected"); 
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    console.log("Not authorised");
                    NotLoggedIn();
                    window.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=012345678901234&scope=publish_stream&redirect_uri=http://www.website.co.uk/bla';
            } else {
                    console.log("User not logged in status unknown");
                    NotLoggedIn();
                    window.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=012345678901234&scope=publish_stream&redirect_uri=http://www.website.co.uk/bla';
            }
        });

  });

    $('div#FBLogin').click(function(){
        window.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=012345678901234&scope=publish_stream&redirect_uri=http://www.danthegeek.co.uk/bla';            
    });


});

function NotLoggedIn(){
    console.timeStamp("notLoggedIn Called");
    // Reset Website
}
```

The two errors I'm getting are with xd_arbiter.php?version=27 which seems to get called.

**JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal
Line 13**

**JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
Line 13**

As a overview, The intention is to have the page auto-redirect to Facebooks login page (not a pop-up window as this doesn't display correctly on mobile devices). If logged in already, no re-direction happens but user can Log Out which will cause a Login button to be displayed which when clicked goes to the Facebook login page, again no pop-up. This all seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if the code structure is exactly how it should be. I don't believe this to be part of the fault. I really wanted to use the facebook social button to login but couldn't get this to work redirecting to the facebook login page, it only seems to cause a pop-up window which is why I show my own Login with Facebook button.

If it wasn't for firebug halting the code all the time saying there was a error I wouldn't even know there was a problem.

The javascript on my test page is quite complicated but even with everything stripped out and running as above I get this problem.

Any help greatly appreciated.